# How do I integrate an application in the sound menu using python?

Tags: indicator, python, application-development, ayatana

I don't necessarily expect a whole tutorial for creating a sound indicator entry here on askubuntu, but I've searched and searched, and I can't seem to find any documentation on creating a sound indicator. Preferably, I'd like to be able to do this in Python. Can someone point me in the right direction??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Documentation for integrating with the sound menu can be [found here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/sound-menu/). Information on [MPRIS](http://mpris.org) is also useful if you want your application to integrate properly.

If you need help you can post to the [ayatana-dev mailing list](https://launchpad.net/~ayatana-dev) or #ayatana IRC on freenode.

Comment: This is very helpful, I'll see what I can dig up with this stuff.

Comment: I came across this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Python version  Is there anything similar for a sound indicator entry?

Comment: Unfortunately no, just the SoundMenu page. Conor is very responsive to anyone who is looking to integrate with the soundmenu, posting on the list will likely get you a quick response.

Comment: First link is dead.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are looking for a python version, you might be interested in [this implementation for exaile](https://github.com/sunng87/Exaile-Soundmenu-Indicator).

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping you mean to "plug into" the current sound indicator applet. if you are designing a media player (like rhythmbox or banshee) then you need to look at the following which is needed to display your media information in the sound indiactor.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Player_Remote_Interfacing_Specification

Comment: I'm actually looking to create a sound indicator entry for an existing media player.

Comment: @greggory.hz Can you add that you're looking to add it to an existing media player and which one in your question so we can leave more detailed answers? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really looking for specifics of implementation ... perhaps just some documentation about how to use the python bindings (python-indicate I think). I want to know how to use this from a general perspective, and not how to add it to a specific media player (once I have the general knowledge, I can take it anywhere else).